# Does forced movement free someone from telekenesis' grip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, forced-movement

I was thinking about a team that was pushing and pulling folks into hazards. I'm wondering if an eldritch blast that pushes the enemy will synergize with a teammate using the telekenesis spell, or if there will actually be anti-synergy.

My suspicion is that forced movement won't break the restraint condition from telekenesis unless you push them out of range, but I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

### *Telekenesis* is unaffected by forced movement

The rule which lets forced movement free someone from a grip is part of the grapple condition (Appendix A of the PHB or Basic Rules):

> The [grapple] condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled away by the thunderwave spell.

While *telekenesis* is fairly similar to a grapple, it is not one. It merely includes the restrained condition, which is distinct. So there's no rule which says forced movement breaks *telekenesis*.

The only range restriction (after the initial targeting of a creature) is that you can't move the target beyond the range with the spell's movement:

> you move the creature up to 30 feet in any direction, including upward but not beyond the range of this spell.

How that interacts with forced movement (from other sources) having moved the target is up your DM. There's a fair argument that the spell automatically breaks (for that target), but also that the range clause only applies if you move it with the spell and so you'd get to keep restraining it. Your DM could also apply a middle ground of applying advantage and/or disadvantage to the contest.